# Linux Mint does not suspend properly

Tags: linux-mint, zfs, suspend

I have been having an issue for some time with Linux Mint. When I put the suspend the computer, it works the first and sometime second time. Otherwise, it ends up getting to a screen saying some processes are still running and eventually hangs (caps lock doesn't even work), forcing me to kill the computer by the power button.

Furthermore, after suspending once, it seems to corrupt my zpool. After turning it back on the "zpool status" always shows one of the mirrors being corrupted (effectively killing the the whole thing). "zpool export" does not work as it says the drives are busy and it seems the only way to fix it is to restart the computer. But the thing is, every time I restart the computer, it all disappears and it works just fine.

I have tried booting the computer with only the boot drive and had the same issue.

The computer used to be dual booted, but is not anymore (Windows Drive was removed for a different computer).

Thank in advance!

The output of inxi -Fxz

```
System:    Host: jr Kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.8.9 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4)
           Distro: Linux Mint 19 Tara
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: Micro-Star model: X299 RAIDER (MS-7A94) v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1.60 date: 11/22/2017
CPU:       8 core Intel Core i7-7820X (-MT-MCP-) 
           arch: Skylake rev.4 cache: 11264 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 57600
           clock speeds: max: 4400 MHz 1: 4099 MHz 2: 2182 MHz 3: 2874 MHz
           4: 4099 MHz 5: 2326 MHz 6: 3800 MHz 7: 1360 MHz 8: 2944 MHz
           9: 4099 MHz 10: 2149 MHz 11: 2798 MHz 12: 4100 MHz 13: 2315 MHz
           14: 3799 MHz 15: 1730 MHz 16: 2922 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] bus-ID: 65:00.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: nvidia (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 2560x1080@60.00hz, 2560x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
           version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.138 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Card-2 NVIDIA GP102 HDMI Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 65:00.1
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-20-generic
Network:   Card: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
           driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k bus-ID: 00:1f.6
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 80366.9GB (0.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD120EMAZ size: 12000.1GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD120EMAZ size: 12000.1GB
           ID-3: /dev/sdc model: WDC_WD120EMAZ size: 12000.1GB
           ID-4: /dev/sdd model: WDC_WD120EMAZ size: 12000.1GB
           ID-5: /dev/sde model: INTEL_SSDSC2BW24 size: 240.1GB
           ID-6: /dev/sdf model: WDC_WDS120G1G0A size: 120.0GB
           ID-7: /dev/sdg model: WDC_WD80EMAZ size: 8001.6GB
           ID-8: /dev/sdh model: WDC_WD80EMAZ size: 8001.6GB
           ID-9: /dev/sdi model: WDC_WD80EMAZ size: 8001.6GB
           ID-10: /dev/sdj model: WDC_WD80EMAZ size: 8001.6GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 219G used: 107G (52%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sde2
RAID:      Device-1: /dev/Mono - ONLINE components: online: sdh1 sdg1 sdj sdi sda sdb sdd sdc
           Info: raid: zfs mirror size: 36.2T available: 33.0T allocated: 3.28T
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 34.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 0.0:53C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 495 Uptime: 1:08 Memory: 23793.3/31840.8MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.5.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.201) inxi: 2.3.56
```